# $D_6$ and cycle notation problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have a hexagon with edges $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and I want to work with its symmetry group $D_6$ in cycle notation. My calculations don't yield consistent results.

For example, I correctly get
$r^4 \cdot r^3 = (AEC)(BFD) \cdot (AD)(BE)(CF) = (BCDEFA) = (ABCDEF) = r$

But on the other hand, I wrongly get
$r^2 \cdot r^3 = (ACE)(BDF) \cdot (AD)(BE)(CF) = (FABCDE) = (ABCDEF) = r$

Where is my error?

Comment: Are you composing from right to left or from left to right?

Comment: I evaluate the first element first, for example in the first line, I send $A$ to $E$ and then to $B$. After that, I send $B$ to $F$ and then to $C$. And so on. But I don't see why this matters because I get the right result in one case.

Comment: In that case, in the second product, you send $A$ to $C$ and then $C$ to $F$, so the cycle should start $AF$ and not $FA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right composition appears to be
$$r^2 \cdot r^3 = (ACE)(BDF) \cdot (AD)(BE)(CF) = (AFEDCB) = r^5.$$

- A to C to F
- F to B to E
- E to A to D
- D to F to C
- C to E to B
- B to D to A

Comment: Ah, yes, this makes sense. So this is a basic problem of my understanding of cycle notation. I think I got it now, thanks!